# Css property to change image position

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I  am doing **html email template**  and in footer table what I am required to do is, book *image is bit popped out of `<td>`*  see the left image that is what I  am required to do  and what I have is on right

[image]

So  please guide me  how I can do it.

```
<tr style=" background-color:#2582bb;">

 <td width="113" height="214" valign="top"> 
 <img src="images/footer.png"  width="113" height="161"/>
  </td>

    </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `div` with `relative` positioning and make your `img` to have an `absolute` position. Adjust the top or bottom parameters and get the desired output.

Here is the solution.

**The Code:**

```
<td width="113" height="214" valign="top"> 
    <div style="position:relative;">
      <img style="position:absolute; top:xx px; bottom: xx px" src="images/footer.png"  width="113" height="161"/>
    </div>
</td>
```

***PS:** Either use top or bottom. xx is a dummy value, insert pixel values to get what you want.*

Comment: oh ,,, thank u very much it worked . i added it and in Dreamweaver design view just dragged it  but up that was drag able after  this code

Comment: will it also work in email clients ?

Comment: Yes it works. But don't drag it. Set manual values after checking the output in browser.

Comment: ok , thank you will  mark it accepted in 2 min  u really did great help  :)

Comment: @NathanLee This has very minimal support in email clients and shouldn't be used in html-email.

Comment: I have worked with this practically and I have not faced any issues till now. - @John

Comment: @NathanLee have you tested it in Litmus/Email on Acid or tested it in the email clients themselves? You've got me curious, skeptical, but curious...

Comment: It also depends on methods on how you integrate your HTML for newsletter. That is very important. So far, I have not faced issues. They work fine. If you are using an email client for mass email, then their methodologies to integrate the HTML may be different. Otherwise, they work fine. - @John

Answer (score 4):

The other answer works for web, but is incorrect for html email - position is not supported in many email clients including Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook 07, 10 & 13, Lotus Notes 6 & 7, Android 2.3 Gmail and Windows Mobile 7. Refer to the [CSS Support Guide from Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) - download the Complete Guide PDF for the full support breakdown.

There are only 2 ways to do this in html email:

1. Cut your image into two and have the protruding top image/part in the above table row
2. If you want to keep it as one full image, you must use a rowspan (or colspan for horizontally protruding)

Here is a rowspan example:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100" height="100" bgcolor="#F5F5F5">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="400" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#252525">
      <img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" src="" width="400" height="300" alt="">
    </td>
    <td width="100" height="100" bgcolor="#F5F5F5">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100" height="200" bgcolor="#959595">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="100" height="200" bgcolor="#959595">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, this should be the accepted answer.

When building emails, you have to build for the lowest possible rendering, that will make sure it never breaks.

Comment: i did not test that if it works  , will check if that one does not work in mentioned clients and will also test yours one to see  if it works